# How to make sure a function returns true in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, controls, undefined, video-capture

Ive been using an embeddable VideoRecorder called AddPipe. https://addpipe.com/docs#javascript-control-api. For the last couple months I have been using the below function to automate the start of the recorder once it loads:

```
function onRecorderReady(recorderId) {

    document.VideoRecorder.record();

}
```

This function randomly stopped working. In the documentation it says to make sure that the embed returns onCamAccess() and onFlashReady() before using the record() method. I tried to change my code to reflect this but I am getting an Error:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.VideoRecorder.record')
Global Code (Example:78)
```

The code I used when I got this error:

```
<script>

function onCamAccess(allowed, recorderId) {

    return true;    

}



function onFlashReady(recorderId) {

     return true;

}

if (onCamAccess()) {

    if (onFlashReady()) {

       document.VideoRecorder.record();   

    }


}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could defer the call until the VideoRecorder object is ready. Just null check it until it's ready if the loading of the script is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to set a timeout function on the .record() method.

```
function onRecorderReady(recorderId) {

setTimeout(function() {document.VideoRecorder.record();}, 1000)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this in the documentation:

> onFlashReady(recorderId);
>   **This function is deprecated**

Maybe you could try the following code:

```
function onCamAccess(allowed, recorderId) {
  document.VideoRecorder.record();
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Could you try this, please?

```
(function () {
  function onRecorderReady(recorderId) {
    document.VideoRecorder.record();
  }
})();
```

Comment: I tried that, the solution I just found was to set a 1 second timeout function, which is strange because this wasn't required before.

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer: I modified my answer. Tell me if it works for you... :)

Comment: No it still doesn't work. The problem is that onRecorderReady doesn't necessarily ensure that `onCamAccess()` is called by the recorder and returns true. Camera access is given about 500 milliseconds after the `onRecorderReady()` event happens. So I had to delay the `.record()` method to account for this. What were you trying to do here?

Comment: Encapsulating your code in IIFEs solves a lot of problems in JavaScript. I thought it would be a viable option in your case, especially to wait for the DOM (`document` must be ready). :)

Comment: I've never heard of IIFEs I will have to do some research, I'm new to Javascript. :)

Comment: IIFEs are great. They are extremely useful in JavaScript. You should definitely learn how to use them because you will meet them very often. ;)